# Abrir PDF ao acessar Website

Tags: pdf

Preciso que ao acessar o website, seja carregado um PDF, alguém sabe informar se tenho que criar alguma index e inserir algum iframe e dizer para abrir o pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecionar o index não ajuda? Se sim, use a estrutura abaixo.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=seu_arquivo.pdf" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```